# How do I deploy Angular app on node.js server

Tags: html, css, node.js

I'm pretty new in Angular. This question seems silly bu Basicaly I created user management app using youtube tutorial. I've installed it globaly.

I just need to send it to someone but I don't know how because when I open it on browser it's not showing me what was shown on localhost:4200. So what am I doing wrong how do I send it to someone?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to deploy your code first run
`ng build --prod` this will generate a build file under /dist.
then copy this file to your nodejs server.

now we have to server the stuff inside the folder, to server static files you will need to install express to your nodejs by `nmp i express`

then your `index.js` or `server.js` will have to look like this.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

also if you do get CORS error just install `npm i cors` and add this `app.use(cors())`

hope this helps